# Parent with a child in the same type - how to map it?

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I don't know how can I correctly convert child of ProductEntity (a type of ProductEntity) to Product.

```
class ProductEntity(id: EntityID<Int>) : BaseIntEntity(id, Products) {
    companion object : BaseIntEntityClass<ProductEntity>(Products)

    var name by Products.name
    var parentProduct by ProductEntity optionalReferencedOn Products.parentProduct

    fun toPojo() = Product(idValue, name, parentProduct?.toPojo())
}

data class Product(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val parentProduct: Product?
)
```

At this time I have the error: Type checking has run into a recursive problem.
Can you tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Please add explicit type to `toPojo` function:
`fun toPojo() : Product = Product(idValue, name, parentProduct?.toPojo())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
class Product(productEntity: ProductEntity) {
    val id: Int = productEntity.idValue
    val name: String = productEntity.name
    val parentProduct = productEntity.parentProduct.toPojo()
}
```